# Befriending all templated classes in other templated class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Look at following code:

```
template <typename T, int d>
class Grid {
   //Following line is what I need to change
   template<int d2> friend class Iterator<T,d,d2>;
}

template <typename T, int d, int d2>
class Iterator{ 
    //some code that use private fields of Grid<T,d>
}

template <typename T, int d>
class Iterator<T,d,0>{
    //This specialized class also need to use private parts of Grid<T,d>
}
```

Both specialized and not specialized Iterator should have access to private parts.
Line:

```
template<int d2> friend class Iterator<T,d,d2>;
```

does not compile with error: partial specialization `Iterator' declared friend

Does anybody know how to replace it?

EDIT:
Thanks to @Xeo comment i was able to make a workaround:

```
template<typename TT, int dd, int d2> friend class Iterator;
```

However this gives friend access to all Iterator templates not only to those one that have matching first and second template parameter.

Comment: What if you forward-declare `Iterator` before defining `Grid`?  I think then the `friend` declaration of specific versions of `Iterator` will work.  Making the `friend` declaration of a class or non-inlined function the first declaration of the item at all never seems to work out quite right.  (I don't know if you have to also forward-declare `Iterator<T,d,0>`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a workaround but it is working:

```
template<typename TT, int dd, int d2> friend class Iterator;
```